# Finding coordinates of pyramid vertices

Tags: vectors

It is stated that the volume of the following right angle triangular pyramid is $288$. I'd like to determine the coordinates of points $A, B, C$.

I realize that $\frac{0.5\cdot x\cdot y\cdot z}{3}=288$, hence $xyz=1728$ (where $x$ is point $A$, $y$ point $B$, $z$ point $C$), yet I'm not sure how to proceed and would appreciate some assistance.

[image]

Comment: If you know nothing more about $x, y, z$ (or the angles that would allow you to deduce some relationships between them), that's as far as you can go.

Comment: @Nick Well, I know that the angle between x and y, and y and z, and x and z is obviously 90 deg. I know that it's a right angle triangular pyramid. But you most likely meant any info. other than that.